# set js functions in jQuery Hotkeys

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, hotkeys

I have a setDisplay function that need to be called as a callback function of jQuery Hotkeys' bind method.

```
function setDisplay(id){
    val = {
        opener : [
            ["#opener", "none"],
            ["#container", "block"]
        ],
        acClose : [
            ["#opener", "block"],
            ["#container", "none"]
        ],
    };
    var sub = val[id];
    var sub1;
    for(i in sub){
        sub1 = sub[i];
        $(sub1[0]).css("display", sub1[1]);
    }
}

   function setHotkeys()
    {
        var open = function(){
            $("#opener").css('display', 'none');
            $("#container").css('display', 'block');
        };
        var close = setDisplay(acClose); // It will work when "close" is defined similar to "open".
        acKey = [
            ["keydown", "ctrl+a", open],
            ["keydown", "ctrl+b", close],
        ];
        sub = [];
        for(i in acKey) {
            sub = acKey[i];
            $(document).bind(sub[0], sub[1], sub[2]);
        }
    }
```

Function setHoykeys worked with variable "open", but "close", as above. What's the problem with setDisplay function? And how could I fix it?

Comment: It's probably not the problem, but that code falls prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) in multiple locations. Declare your variables.  (`val` and `i` in the first method; `sub`, `acKey`, and `i` in the second.)

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of doing `sub = []` when the next thing you're going to do is overwrite that with `sub = acKey[i]`? `sub = acKey[i]` *overwrites* the value of the `sub` variable with the value of the `acKey[i]` variable; it does not (for instance) add to an array. (To do that, you'd use `sub.push(acKey[i])`).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've changed the variable (`sub=[]` either), but this function still returned error "Uncaught TypeError: Object ctrl+b has no method 'apply' " with var "close".